# Self-hosted gitlab CI: upload to package registry from within Makefile with CI_JOB_TOKEN

Tags: makefile, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to upload a generic package to my self-hosted gitlab package registry, according to the example [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/generic_packages/index.html#publish-a-generic-package-by-using-cicd).

It works according to the example, but now I want to instead call `make` from the CI and use a similar call to `curl` *within* the `Makefile`. This doesn't work, presumably because the value of `CI_JOB_TOKEN` passed to the `Makefile` is `[MASKED]` (verbatim)?

I tried a few tricks, like

```yaml
script: |
  make JOB_TOKEN=$CI_JOB_TOKEN upload
```

and then using `JOB_TOKEN` in the `Makefile`, but none work...
(The other CI variables are read perfectly fine from the env by the `Makefile`)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

The issue is not the passing of `CI_JOB_TOKEN`, which works perfectly fine, but an issue where the reverse proxy (with WAF - Web Application Firewall (in my case `modsecurity`) apparently blocks these specific api requests.

When the CI runner is on the same LAN as the gitlab server, the local (http) address can be taken, which works. Another solution (untested) would have been to modify the WAF to allow the necessary api calls through.